# What is the point of Groups in TestNG?

Tags: testng

TestNG has Groups which you can specify in your test classes, and in the TestNG.xml file which controls execution.

My problem is - it does not actually do anything.

I thought I would be able to run all the classes in a group by just running the group.

What is it actually useful for?

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups

I have TestNG.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="tests">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestNGCustomReportListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="5" name="firefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="login" />
            </run>
        </groups>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My classes are all prefixes like this:

```
public class LoginTest extends CrossBrowserTest{

@Test(groups = {"login"})
public void loginTest (){
```

The result of running this? No classes were run:

```
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

It does not do what it is meant to?

So I did some experiment with this.

I put the groups section at the top of a large testng.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="tests">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestNGCustomReportListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="5" name="firefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="login" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.login.LoginTest" />
            <class name="tests.login.AutoLogOutTest" />
            <class name="tests.login.AutoLogOutWithRestApiTest" />
            <class name="tests.login.ChangePasswordTest" />
            <class name="tests.login.SwitchCustomerProjectsTest" /> 
            <class name="tests.login.ForgotPasswordResetTest" />
            <class name="tests.login.EditUserNameTest" />

            <class name="tests.layers.EnableLayerTest" />
            <class name="tests.layers.EnableLayerStyleTest" />
            <class name="tests.layers.ChangeLayerNameTest" />
            <class name="tests.layers.ChangeStyleNameTest" />
            <class name="tests.layers.ChangeStyleColourTest" />

            <!-- etc -->

            </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

This time, it did only run the group selected, but it did not  do this stuff, and therefore did not log in:

```
    @Parameters("browser")

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(@Optional("firefox") String browser) {
    // compares the value of parameter name with Firefox, if its firefox then it
    // will lauch firefox and run the script.
    debug.print(thisClass + " CrossBrowserTest.beforeTest." );

    initialiseDriver(browser);

    loggedInPage = LoginUtility.login(driver);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short it is used for grouping.

Let's start from testng.xml. It is using following structure:

```
<suite name="TestNG">

<test name="Nopackage">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="nopackage"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <classes>
    <class name="NoPackageTest" />
  </classes>
</test>
```

As you can see groups and classes are on the same level. If you want to run all tests in group you have to specify classes/packages to be invoked and groups, like intersecting set.

Please see [testng.xml and related class for example](https://github.com/RocketRaccoon/TestNG-Examples/blob/master/src/test/resources/testng.xml)

Also you have `@BeforeGroup` and `@AfterGroup` annotations which will help in context manipulation.

Main case when I'm using groups is managing different setups for different test methods per class. For example `@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)` is running for all methods in class, but `@BeforeMethod(groups = "my_group")` will run only for methods marked with `my_group`.

And the last one, modern reporting tools are supporting view per groups, so you can use them as tags.

Comment: @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true) causes a syntax error: Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Comment: Actualy I has been wrong a little bit. You need to specify groups and classes in xml. I have updated my answer.